# Service based Database not closed

Tags: c#, database

I have problem when I do connection to Service based Database, to mdf file
after I opened the connection I cant closed it.

That is my Code:
Create 2 buttons and 1 OpenDialogFile

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString(db.mdf));
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        {
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Database File|*.mdf|All files |*.*";
openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "mdf";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "db.mdf";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
return;
}
textbox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

After click on the first button the file in used and cannot do the second button

My Problem:
i got connection string i can get the DataBased connected;
but after i do it such as: Conn.Open();
no metter what i do 
Conn.close();
or anything else the file, the DB.MDF file is in used until i closed the whole project...
it mean if i wanna 
open it and closed it i need open and close the project...

Edit:
Try even that:

```
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectString))
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
```

still not worked

Comment: Use "using" when opening your connection string, e.g. using (SqlConnection conn...  This should dispose of the connection correctly when the button1_Click method exits.

Comment: "Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent."  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Still not working
not using like that:


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString(db.mdf));
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the connection pools:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString(db.mdf))
{
    conn.Open();
    conn.Close();
}
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

Comment: Also might need to detach the the db via `sp_detach_db`.

Comment: Joel's answer is correct, you should not be doing this with SQL "Server".

Comment: That Work the 
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

Answer (score 1):

You **never** directly use a `*.mdf` file. Instead, what happens is that Sql Server is already running somewhere in the background, and you tell Sql Server to attach to that file for you. Then you talk to Sql Server and open a connection to the database that Sql Server just attached.

When you close the connection, you are no longer connected to the database, but **Sql Server is still running and still using the file.** When you later go to try to open that file, it's still locked in use, and so you see the error from your question. Now you ask, "How can I tell Sql Server to release the file?" There are ways, but that's really the wrong question.

Instead, you need to ask if what you're doing fits with how Sql Server works. You see, Sql Server is not intended to work as a local data store for desktop applications. It really isn't. Sql Server is intended to live on a dedicated server somewhere, providing access to databases that have many many people connecting and making changes all at once. It's connection and operating methods reflect this, and therefore it's just not a good choice as a simple local data store used for desktop applications.

*I love Sql Server, but if all you want to do is open a file and read or save a few records on your local machine from a local application, there are much better options available: Sql Server Compact (not Express) Edition, Sqlite, and even MS Access are all better choices for this.*

While I'm here, never ever ever call `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` yourself. You see, Sql Server supports a finite number of connections. If your code calls `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` to end those connections manually, you're likely leaving a chance that an exception will occur in the method before reaching that function call, and the connection will never be closed. Do this enough, and suddenly you've locked yourself out of the database server. The best way to close the connection is **not** call those methods yourself, but instead let the framework do it for you, through the `using` mechanism:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    cn.Open();
    //do stuff with cn

}  // cn WILL be closed at the end of this brace, **even if an exception is thrown**
// At no point did I ever use cn.Close(); or cn.Dispose(); the framework made sure it happened for me
```

Comment: i try 3 things
with/without Dipsose,Closed,using statment, normal,var
no one of them worked the file still in used

Comment: @AsafShazar If you're looking at the code sample, you missed the point of the answer.

Comment: the problem is the Close Connected not worked but i found the answer
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
that worked for me
the file now is not use and i can edit him in other project without closing everything

Comment: i just now understand what you mean.
i know , hehe i just give that the fast close just to show my problem
i already using the connection, dont worry, i have full code with insert delete and update , but the problem was it not full closed the connection, so i give that fast connect and close connection to show my problem , now that i know how to full close the connection i can use that in my really project

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help
after using that

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

the file stop to be used and i can use it in other project/Form in my Full Project
so i dont need to close the Whole Project